# why can't I comment lines in visual mode

Tags: vim

I want to comment several lines in my .vimrc, the usual way I do it is `:x,ys/^/"/` and 
x stands for the start line number and y stands for the line number of the last line. I
read some post which said in visual mode this task can be done by the following step:

1 Select your lines with VISUAL BLOCK

2 press I to insert before all highlighted lines.

3 type your comment charact , in this case should be `"`

4 then ESC

I fllowed the above steps and met met problems in step 2 . the thing is when I select the lines in Visual mode and press I ,  vim ( I use version7.2) go back to insert mode and the cursor back to the start of the first line. so if you continue to do the step 3 and step 4, you end up in just inserting `"` at the start the first line , far from what I want to achieve.

so could you point out what's wrong with the recipe ? thanks in advance

---

dammit, it's my fault . The recipe is absolutely right, If I'm patient enough to  enter ESC
in step 4, I see what I.
want to see......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the block in visual mode, and then use `:s/^/"/`. When you press `:`, vim will automatically start the command with `:'<,'>` which indicates the effective range is the marked visual block.

Actually, your proposed sequence works also, as long as you use visual *block* mode, started with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> (that is, vim should display `-- VISUAL BLOCK --` on the status line).

Answer (score 2):

I find this plugin very helpful with pretty much all of my commenting needs.
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218

Favorites... (work both in visual and normal mode)

Toggle comment.

```
,c<SPACE>
```

Yank selected lines before commenting them out. (can then paste with p)

```
,cy
```

Toggle lines individually.

```
,ci
```

Supports a great number of file types and comes with documentation.